# Angular - Tooltip makes other elements move

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ngx-bootstrap

In the body, I have a button and a form, whenever the tooltip shows, the form (which is below the button) moves because a new HTML tag for the tooltip is added to the DOM. Is there anyway I can fix this?

```
<button [tooltip]="'Click Me!'">Click</button>
<form>...</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML default for tooltip:

```
<button title="Click Me!">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried that, but I preferred the bootstrap-style tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `container="body"` option.
Example  - https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#append-to-body